# Omission of form tag and security concerns. Advice please

Tags: jquery

I want to use straight JQuery to submit a form and omit the form tag all together. If I do this, are there any security issues that I need to be concerned with?

Apart from the user not being able to use the site if his javascript is turned off, should I be concerned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only security concern that comes to my mind here is that you should make sure to protect the submission from [CSRF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) attacks (probably by including a server-generated token).

Comment: THanks Adam. Does CSRF only work for query strings? I'm using sessions for this part of the site.

Comment: It can be dangerous both for GET and POST requests.